# Recuperar información de extensión Google Chrome al utilizarla de nuevo

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

Me gustaría saber como puedo almacenar información de una extensión de Google Chrome de forma que al utilizarla de nuevo, se cargue con los últimos ajustes guardados.

Estoy utilizando `storage`, pero no se como puedo lograr que al hacer click en el icono de la extensión, se solicite la información oportuna.

Ahora mismo, mi extensión solamente tiene un checkbox. Me gustaría que, si marco el checkbox y cierro la extensión, cuando vuelva a usarla me aparezca ya marcada.

Mi `background.js` es el siguiente:

```
const active = document.getElementById('active');

const setStatus = (status) =>
{
    chrome.storage.sync.set({ active: status }, () =>
    {
        console.log('Value is set to ' + status);
    });
};

const getStatus = (callback) =>
{
    chrome.storage.sync.get(['active'], callback);

};

const getHightLightedText = () =>
{
    document.addEventListener('mouseup', event =>
    {
        if (window.getSelection().toString() != "")
        {
            console.log(window.getSelection().toString());
        }
    });
};



chrome.runtime.onInstalled.addListener(details =>
{
    setStatus(true);
});
chrome.tabs.onActivated.addListener(async (info) =>
{
    getStatus((status) =>
    {
        if (status.active)
        {
            active.checked = true;
        } else
        {
            active.checked = false;
        }
    });
    await chrome.scripting.executeScript({
        target: { tabId: info.tabId },
        func: getHightLightedText,
    }).catch(console.error);

});

active.addEventListener('click', async () =>
{
    if (active.checked)
    {
        setStatus(true);
        getStatus((status) => { console.log(status.active); });
    } else
    {
        setStatus(false);
    }
});
```

Gracias de antemano por la ayuda

Answer (score 0):

La respuesta era muy sencilla. Al final con un window.onload lo he podido hacer muy facilmente:

```
window.onload = function ()
{
    getStatus((status) =>
    {
        if (status.active)
        {
            active.checked = true;
        } else
        {
            active.checked = false;
        }
    });
};
```